# Derivation of Vieta's formulae

Tags: linear-algebra

I was looking up for the proof of this property:

> For a matrix $A$ (which is associated to an endomorphism $f$ of a vector space $V$ over a field $F$), its determinant is the product of its eigenvalues, and its trace is their sum.

One of the approaches for the proof was the usage of Vieta's formulae, which really makes it easier. But I didn't find a complete proof for these formulae.

> Could anyone write its proof (or a hint) or provide me with a useful source for its proof? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What field are you working over?

Comment: If $p(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}x+a_n=(x-b_1)\cdot...\cdot(x-b_n)$, you can multiply the RHS out and collect terms. This, in general, is somewhat tedious, but at least the coefficients $a_1$ and $a_n$, which are precisely trace and determinant, can be easily obtained.

Comment: @Thorgott:  excellent point, could become an answer; just one minor quibble:  you mean trace and determinant up to a possible factor of $-1$, right?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  if I am not mistaken, the $\det$ term has a factor of $-1$ when $n$ is odd; the trace term is always $(-\sum \text{eigenvalues}) x$. Cheers!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  I shoudl have written $(-\sum \text{eigenvalues})x^{n - 1}$.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertLewis; I think you are correct

Comment: Use the initial comment of @Thorgott from the **opposite** direction.  $$\left[\prod_{i=1}^n (x + b_i)\right] = x^n + \left[\sum_{a=1}^n f(a)x^{(n-a)}\right]$$ where $f(a)$ represents the summation of the $\binom{n}{a}$ distinct terms, where each term represents the product of $a$ distinct elements from $\{b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n\}$.  Here, it is understood that if (for example) $b_1$ happens to equal $b_2$, that the usage of $b_1$ and $b_2$ when computing $f(a)$ are considered *distinct usages*.